# random number either 65- 90[a-z] or 97-122[A-Z]

Tags: c, random, ascii

I need a method in C that the random number between decimal 65-90 [`a` - `z`] and decimal 97-122 [`A` - `Z`] returns. If I call the method the method must be a different number give back what he has previously given How can I do this in C ?

Comment: homework? No problem if it is: just let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char rand_az_AZ() {
    char val = rand() % 52;
    if (val < 26) {
        val += 'a';
    } else {
        val -= 26;
        val += 'A';
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: wooow this is incredible this is it what i need thank you soooooo much

Comment: one more question about this example how can i fix it when i call the programm tree time successively and he gives me different number ?

Comment: Call srand (time(NULL)); at beginning of your program.

Comment: Congratulations... soon you'll get your CS degree :P

Comment: i cant find anyword to say to you thank you soooooooooo much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Can you do a random number between 0 and 52 (excluding 52)?

Do it! Add 65 to the result. if the value is 91 or greater, add 6 to the 2nd result. *Voilà!*

Ohh ... if the number is the same as the one from last time (you saved last number in a static variable, didn't you?), do it again :)

Answer (score 1):

Given a function `random_in_range` that returns random integers in the range [0,n):

```
char random_letter()
{
    static const char letters[] = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                  "ABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    return letters[random_in_range(sizeof(letters))];
}
```

(A simple implementation of `random_in_range(n)` would return `rand() % n`. That wouldn't return uniformly distributed integers, though.)

Comment: i muss do it with rand() and srand()

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

Again updated per Interjay's comment.

**UPDATE**

Made changes per Interjay's comment.  Also changed pickChar so that we aren't relying on a particular encoding.

Warning: using the `%` operator to map the results of `rand` to a different range is not recommended.  Low-order bit patterns are not guaranteed to be evenly distributed, and you could get a non-normal distribution of values.  It works well enough for class assignments, but the procedure below should give better results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randInRange(int min, int max) 
{
  return (int)(((double) rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX + 1)) * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

char pickChar(void)
{
  char val; 
  int cas = randInRange(0, 1);

  if (cas == 1)
    val = (char) randInRange('A', 'Z');
  else
    val = (char) randInRange('a', 'z');

  return val;
}

int main(void)
{
  char results[11] = {0};
  int i;

  srand(time(NULL));  // seed the random number generator

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof results - 1; i++)
    results[i] = pickChar();

  printf("Random string: %s\n", results);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `randInRange` function can give a value over `max` if `rand()` returned `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: Actually, it's still buggy: Now `max` will almost never be returned. This should work: `(int)(((double) rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX+1)) * (max-min+1)) + min`.